# parse starlett.response Responses content=bytearray

Tags: python, starlette

Having the following piece of code:

```
Response(
         content=bytearray(my_var), 
         headers={"Content-Type": "plain/text"}
        )
```

Which var should I pass to my_var for making this work? I have manually edited "Content-Type" of the header, changing it to some other would that change the result?

This is for a test, therefore I don't have margin to change anything.

All the errors I get are related to encode and decode from bytearray.

Comment: What are the errors?